# How to plot multiple y-axes?

Tags: gnuplot

I saw this graph and only for the curiosity sake was wondering whether it was possible to plot figure with multiple y-axis as in the figure [image]

Many thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As andyras wrote, you can use the second y-axis if you only have two datasets. In this case, you also need to to

```
set ytics nomirror # remove the tickmarks of the left ayis on the right side
set y2tics         # make the right y-axis 'visible'
```

If you want to plot more than one dataset, I would suggest to use `multiplot`. You can overlay several independent plots and put a unique offset to the y-axis for each of them.
However, you need to take care that the number of y-tics and y-tick positions is the same.

**Plot:**

[image]

(I did not care about the key here, this still needs adjustment)

**Code:**

```
set multiplot


set xrange[0:10]

# We need place to the left, so make the left margin 30% of screen
set lmargin screen 0.3

##### first plot

set ytics 0.4
set yrange[-1.2:1.2]

set ylabel "Voltage" textcolor rgb "red"

plot sin(x)


##### Second plot

set ytics 1
set yrange[-3:3]

set ytics offset  -8, 0
set ylabel "Current" offset -8, 0 textcolor rgb "green"

plot 3*cos(x) linecolor 2

##### Third plot

set ytics 0.5
set yrange[-1.5:1.5]


set ytics offset -16, 0
set ylabel "Power" offset -16, 0  textcolor rgb "blue"
plot 3*sin(x)*cos(x) linecolor 3

unset multiplot
```

Comment: Thanks Sweber! But that offset command is still confusing. What is the reference line for offset -8 or -16?

Comment: The default offset is 0, hence the reference is the voltage axis in my plot. If you specify it, you can also give a unit, e.g. `offset screen -0.2, 0` which means 20% of the window width to the left. Without the `screen`, I think it takes something like character width/heigth. Character size is a uncommon, but often useful unit.

Comment: I've followed your example above but don't know how to separate those 3 (2 in my case) labels in the upper right corner. I tried 'offset t -1,0' and such but that didn't work. Now I just emptied them out: ' t "" '. Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can have two y axes for free, e.g.

```
plot x, x**2 axes x1y2
```

The `axes` specification lets you put things on `x1y1`, `x2y1`, etc. If you want more than two things plotted on the same y axes you have to normalize things yourself:

```
plot 'data1.dat' using 1:($2/MAX_1), \
  'data2.dat' using 1:($2/MAX_2), \
  'data3.dat' using 1:($s/MAX_3)
```

The variables `MAX_X` can be precalculated by using the `stats` command in gnuplot 4.6+, or you can put them in manually.