# How do I plot multiple Y axis for a single X axis in a single Gnuplot window?

Tags: gnuplot

I am using the 32-bit version of gnuplot in a Window 7 "Professional" OS Environment (...sadly!) and I want to do a "stack-plot" of boxes using ONLY ONE x-axis for ALL which is "TIME" in the format of a series of "Dates".

ALL of the gnuplot code works but, each of the plots uses its own individual x-axis which consumes a lot of graphing real estate.

I also need to be able to have variable y-axis scales for each of the stacked-plots...

Here is the "labeled" (CSV) data file:

> Date,Time,Weight(kg),Height(cm),BMI,BP Max.(mmHg),BP Min.(mmHg),P/min,% Fat 09/09/2015,13:16:00,77.4,171,26.5,121,73,75,22.5 16/07/2015,09:14:34,76.9,170,26.6,111,70,76,23.5 26/06/2015,18:14:48,76.9,170,26.6,123,72,78,23.2 19/06/2015,08:45:42,77,172,26,96,60,89,22.1 15/06/2015,12:29:48,77.7,170,26.9,117,73,87,23.6 15/06/2015,12:15:58,77.8,170,26.9,127,76,77,23.7 15/06/2015,12:11:05,77.7,171,26.6,118,74,83,22.8 23/03/2015,16:39:55,78.6,170,27.2,119,72,78,24 20/03/2015,09:07:30,77.6,169,27.2,138,74,77,24.1 09/01/2015,14:30:00,79.2,170,27.4,114,71,75,24.1 07/10/2014,16:06:00,78.4,171,26.8,119,73,108,24.8 07/10/2014,16:08:00,78.4,170,27.1,109,72,75,25.1 15/09/2014,08:18:23,76.9,171,26.3,116,69,102,24.8 15/09/2014,09:20:27,76.7,172,25.9,132,76,91,21 04/09/2014,12:05:00,75.6,169,26.5,115,71,96,25.4 01/04/2014,11:18:00,76.2,171,26,115,69,70,22.9 19/03/2014,09:48:23,75.3,171,25.8,113,69,55,22.1 14/03/2014,10:39:29,75.6,170,26.2,108,69,78,22.5 05/03/2014,16:45:00,75.9,170,26.3,129,73,84,23.3 09/05/2013,17:31:00,74.5,171,25.5,135,75,92,21

And here is the "current" gnuplot Code that I am using to generate the 5 stacked plots:

```
reset
set terminal windows size 1325, 625
set multiplot layout 5, 1 title "Individual Employee Biometric Data vs. Time"
set xlabel "DATE"
set timestamp
set key outside 
set key center right 
set pointsize 1.0 
set grid lw 1 
set timefmt "%d/%m/%Y" 
set xdata time 
set format x "%d/%m/%Y" 
set xrange [ "09/05/2013\t0000" : "09/09/2015\t0000" ] noreverse nowriteback 
set datafile sep ','
set arrow from 10.0,0 to 10.0, 0.5 lw 3
set label ' ' at 10.2,0.03
set label '(C) 2015' at 2050.0,-0.85 
set border lw 2

set yrange [73.0:80.0] 
set ylabel "(kg)" 
plot 'K8.dat' using 1:3 title "BODY\nWEIGHT" with linespoints lw 2 lt rgb 'red'

set yrange [25.0:30.0] 
set ylabel "kg/m^2" 
plot 'K8.dat' using 1:5 title "BODY\nMASS\nINDEX" with linespoints lw 2 lt rgb 'green'

set yrange [50.0:150.0] 
set ylabel "(mmHg)" 
plot 'K8.dat' using 1:6 title "SYS" with linespoints lw 2 lt rgb 'blue', \ 'K8.dat' using 1:7 title "DIAS" with linespoints lw 2 lt rgb 'coral'

set yrange [40.0:120.0] 
set ylabel "(bpm)" 
plot 'K8.dat' using 1:8 title "HEART\nRATE" with linespoints lw 2 lt rgb 'purple'

set xlabel "DATE" 
set yrange [15.0:30.0] 
set ylabel "(%)" 
plot 'K8.dat' using 1:9 title "BODY\nFAT" with linespoints lw 2 lt rgb 'orange'
```

PS - This code is from a previous GNUPlot routine so "excuse" the '#" commenting-out...

Here is my current image. You will see that the y-axis vary for each plot but the x-axis remains the same for all BUT consumes a great deal of "real estate"... I would only like to have a single labeled x-axis on this multi-plot...

[image: my current]

Comment: Could you make a mock-up of what you want the plot to look like? The image I'm getting when I think "stacked box plot" does imho not quite make sense for your data.

Comment: ...SURE!!! Many Thanks! is there a way that I can get it to you?

Comment: Hi Daniel! I have an image for your review! How can I send it to you? MANY THANKS! LEO

Comment: I'm pretty sure stack overflow offers the option of uploading images as attachments to your post, otherwise use a web-based image hosting service.

Comment: Hi Daniel! Thanks again for your willingness to help! Here is a link:  http://i1382.photobucket.com/albums/ah270/lgdeneault/SAMPLE_zpsec1ejpoh.png    You will see that the y-axis vary for each plot but the x-axis remains the same for all BUT consumes a great deal of "real estate"...  I would only like to have a single labeled x-axis on this multi-plot...   Best! LEE

Comment: Ok, I get what you mean by stacked plots now. To my knowledge, having several y-axes (more than 2) above a single x axis is not possible.

Comment: Btw. it's "gnuplot", not "GNUplot". There is no connection with the FSF's GNU project.

Comment: @Daniel Definitely possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27390317

Answer (score 2):

You can use `multiplot` to stack several plots on top of each other. You just have to switch off the plot borders appropriately for each, see `help set border`, and unset the abscissa `xtics` for all but the lowermost plot.

```
set multiplot
set origin 0.1, 0.1
set size 0.9,0.3
set xrange [a:b]
plot "first"
set origin 0.1,0.4
unset xtics
set border 2 # only plot left border
plot "second"
set origin 0.1,0.7
plot "third"
unset multi
```

Crucial is fixing the xrange for all plots, because after switching off the xtics for the following plots, you can't see if it is actually identical.

Comment: Definitively shorter than my solution. Nice trick with the border.

Answer (score 0):

(too long for a comment)

Ok, I get what you mean by stacked plots now. To my knowledge, having several y-axes (more than 2) above a single x axis is not possible.

What you COULD however do is try to fake more than 2 axes by plotting all data in the roughly 30...150 range on the y(1)-axis, and all data in the 15...30 range on the y2axis. However, the lines would be all kind of overlapping and not as cleanly separated.

Another alternative would be to first normalize all data into an e.g. 0...10 range by subtracting the min value and dividing by max-min, then stacking these on top of each other by adding 0 for the first line, 10 for the second, and so on. However, you would then have to add hand-made y-axis tics (which is possible but somewhat bothersome).

Actually, here is a working template for the fancier solution I outlined above (implemented for three data sets, but can be extended to basically arbitrarily many)

```
reset

set datafile separator ","

inputfile = 'data0.txt'

stats inputfile using 3 name 'STATS_WEIGHT'
STATS_WEIGHT_range = STATS_WEIGHT_max - STATS_WEIGHT_min

stats inputfile using 4 name 'STATS_HEIGHT'
STATS_HEIGHT_range = STATS_HEIGHT_max - STATS_HEIGHT_min

stats inputfile using 9 name 'STATS_FAT'
STATS_FAT_range = STATS_FAT_max - STATS_FAT_min

# more stats for further data -- apparently needs to be BEFORE the date/time stuff

set timefmt "%d/%m/%Y" 
set xdata time 
set format x "%d/%m/%Y" 
set xrange [ "09/05/2013\t0000" : "09/09/2015\t0000" ] noreverse nowriteback 


# define the offset at which the fake y-axes start; decrease or increase offsetIncrease for spacing (effectively: blank labels) between 'graphs'
startYTicsOffset = 0
numberOfFakeYTicsPerData = 6
scalingFactor = 1.0/(numberOfFakeYTicsPerData - 1.0)
offsetIncrease = numberOfFakeYTicsPerData + 0.5

#to get rid of actual yrange numbering, set a dummy label that will be overwritten
set ytics ("dummy" 0)

#increase total actual yrange factor as needed for additional series
set yrange [0: 3 * offsetIncrease] 

#add tics for weight, note that %.Xf prints the number with X decimals
do for[i=0:numberOfFakeYTicsPerData-1]{
  set ytics add (sprintf("%.0f kg", STATS_WEIGHT_min + i * scalingFactor * STATS_WEIGHT_range) startYTicsOffset+i)
}

#add tics for height
startYTicsOffset = startYTicsOffset + offsetIncrease
do for[i=0:numberOfFakeYTicsPerData-1]{
  set ytics add (sprintf("%.1f cm", STATS_HEIGHT_min + i * scalingFactor * STATS_HEIGHT_range) startYTicsOffset+i)
}

#add tics for fat - I couldn't figure out how to get gnuplot to print actual '%' character in sprintf directive (should be '%%' but doesn't appear to work)
startYTicsOffset = startYTicsOffset + offsetIncrease
do for[i=0:numberOfFakeYTicsPerData-1]{
  set ytics add (sprintf("%.1f percent", STATS_FAT_min + i * scalingFactor * STATS_FAT_range) startYTicsOffset+i)
}

###### ... add further tics ...


plot inputfile using 1:( 0 * offsetIncrease + ($3 - STATS_WEIGHT_min)/ (STATS_WEIGHT_range * scalingFactor) ) w lp title "weight",\
     inputfile using 1:( 1 * offsetIncrease + ($4 - STATS_HEIGHT_min)/ (STATS_HEIGHT_range * scalingFactor) ) w lp title "height",\
     inputfile using 1:( 2 * offsetIncrease + ($9 - STATS_FAT_min)   / (STATS_FAT_range * scalingFactor) )    w lp title "fat %"
### ... add further data ...
```

by the way: if you post or edit a question or an answer, try clicking the image icon above the editing window. It will open a little window where you can drag and drop images directly without needing a web hosting service. Like that:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative suggestion where you don't have to calculate and set the size and origin of each individual subplot. Instead, it is using the `multiplot` option `margins`, available since gnuplot 5.0.0 (Jan. 2015). The subplots will have the same height, but only the lowest one has the x-axis label.

**Data:** `SO33663577.dat`

```
Date,Time,Weight(kg),Height(cm),BMI,BP Max.(mmHg),BP Min.(mmHg),P/min,% Fat
09/09/2015,13:16:00,77.4,171,26.5,121,73,75,22.5
16/07/2015,09:14:34,76.9,170,26.6,111,70,76,23.5
26/06/2015,18:14:48,76.9,170,26.6,123,72,78,23.2
19/06/2015,08:45:42,77,172,26,96,60,89,22.1
15/06/2015,12:29:48,77.7,170,26.9,117,73,87,23.6
15/06/2015,12:15:58,77.8,170,26.9,127,76,77,23.7
15/06/2015,12:11:05,77.7,171,26.6,118,74,83,22.8
23/03/2015,16:39:55,78.6,170,27.2,119,72,78,24
20/03/2015,09:07:30,77.6,169,27.2,138,74,77,24.1
09/01/2015,14:30:00,79.2,170,27.4,114,71,75,24.1
07/10/2014,16:06:00,78.4,171,26.8,119,73,108,24.8
07/10/2014,16:08:00,78.4,170,27.1,109,72,75,25.1
15/09/2014,08:18:23,76.9,171,26.3,116,69,102,24.8
15/09/2014,09:20:27,76.7,172,25.9,132,76,91,21
04/09/2014,12:05:00,75.6,169,26.5,115,71,96,25.4
01/04/2014,11:18:00,76.2,171,26,115,69,70,22.9
19/03/2014,09:48:23,75.3,171,25.8,113,69,55,22.1
14/03/2014,10:39:29,75.6,170,26.2,108,69,78,22.5
05/03/2014,16:45:00,75.9,170,26.3,129,73,84,23.3
09/05/2013,17:31:00,74.5,171,25.5,135,75,92,21
```

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>=5.0.0, Jan. 2015)

```
### multiplot with equal subplot height and only one x label
reset session

FILE = "SO33663577.dat"
set datafile sep ','
set key out center right
set timefmt "%d/%m/%Y"
set xdata time
set format x ""
set grid x,y

set multiplot layout 5,1 title "Individual Employee Biometric Data vs. Time" margins 0.10,0.83,0.10,0.95

    set ylabel "(kg)" 
    set yrange [73.0:80.0] 
    plot FILE u 1:3 w lp lw 2 lt rgb 'red' ti "BODY\nWEIGHT"

    set ylabel "kg/m^2" 
    set yrange [25.0:30.0] 
    plot FILE u 1:5 title "BODY\nMASS\nINDEX" w lp lw 2 lt rgb 'green'

    set ylabel "(mmHg)" 
    set yrange [50.0:150.0] 
    plot FILE u 1:6 title "SYS" w lp lw 2 lt rgb 'blue', \
         FILE u 1:7 title "DIAS" w lp lw 2 lt rgb 'coral'

    set ylabel "(bpm)" 
    set yrange [40.0:120.0] 
    plot FILE u 1:8 title "HEART\nRATE" w lp lw 2 lt rgb 'purple'

    set format x "%Y\n%d/%m"
    set xlabel "DATE" 
    set ylabel "(%)" 
    set yrange [15.0:30.0] 
    plot FILE u 1:9 title "BODY\nFAT" w lp lw 2 lt rgb 'orange'
    
unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]