how can I fix the varying size of plots in multiplot due to axis tic size?
I'm plotting multiple data sets with multiplot. I want them to be aligned along the x-axis. All data sets ARE on the same x-axis, but since their y-axis labels take up a different amount of space, the plots end up being of different size. I looked into set margin, but I think that would just shift the plot and not actual make it longer/short to fit the other plot sizes?
How can I set the actual plot size (minus axis)?


If all plots have the same x-range you might want to omit the xticlabels except for the lowest plot, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/78168755/7295599 Check help multiplot and especially the options spacing and margins.

You can pin one or more of the plot borders to an absolute position on the page.  Just make sure there is enough room to the outside of it for the labels to fit:
   set lmargin at screen 0.15
   set rmargin at screen 0.8
   set multiplot layout 8,1
       plot ...
       plot ...
       etc
   unset multiplot


set margin AT SCREEN, that's it! Thank you!
