# Gnuplot\Multiplot: Three yaxis and three plots

Tags: plot, gnuplot, yaxis

Is it possible to have three plots using `multiplot`, where every plot has three yaxis?
I know it is possible to use three axis on one plot as seen here: [How to plot multiple y-axes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27390317/how-to-plot-multiple-y-axes)

I would like to have three of these diagrams among each other.

Here is what I´m looking for:

[image]

Thank you very much!

EDIT:
I managed to get a similar diagram. With the code I posted I get following diagram:

[3x3 diagramm Gnuplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qljU3.png)

Now I dont know how to get the ytics(I mean the horizontal small lines on the y1 axis) to the y3 axis (Too many tics on the yaxis). If this isn´t possible I have to get all tics in the same position (?).
Another problem is the space on the right of the canvas.

```
set terminal pngcairo size 2400,600
set output "GNUPLOT3x3.png"
set multiplot layout 3,2

set lmargin 30
set bmargin 3
set rmargin 20  
set tmargin 1

set xlabel "Taktzeit [s]" 
set ylabel "Obere Temperatur in K" 
set xrange [ 0.00000 : 30.0000 ] 
set ytics nomirror

set y2tics
set ytics textcolor rgb "violet"
set ylabel textcolor rgb "violet"
set y2tics textcolor rgb "green"
set y2label textcolor rgb "green"
unset key 
f(x)=293.15*(1/(1-933.32*x/(20000000*0.0062*log(1.61))))
plot f(x) t "\\tiny Temperatur" lt rgb "violet" axes x1y1, sin(x) axes x1y2

set xlabel " " 
set ylabel "Dritte YAchse Abb.1" 
set xrange [ 0.00000 : 30.0000 ] 
set ytics nomirror
set ytics offset -10,0
set ylabel offset -10,0
set ytics textcolor rgb "red"
set ylabel textcolor rgb "red"
set origin 0,0.666666667
plot 1 

set xlabel "Taktzeit" 
set ylabel "Obere Temperatur in K" 
set xrange [ 0.00000 : 30.0000 ] 
set ytics nomirror
set y2tics
set ytics offset 0,0
set ylabel offset 0,0
set ytics textcolor rgb "violet"
set ylabel textcolor rgb "violet"
plot 2 axes x1y1 lt rgb "violet", sin(x) axes x1y2
unset key 

set origin 0,0.333333333333
set xlabel "Taktzeit" 
set ylabel "Obere Temperatur in K" 
set xrange [ 0.00000 : 30.0000 ] 
set ytics nomirror
set ytics offset -10,0
set ylabel offset -10,0
set ytics textcolor rgb "red"
set ylabel textcolor rgb "red"
plot cos(x)
unset key 

set xlabel "Taktzeit" 
set ylabel "Obere Temperatur in K" 
set xrange [ 0.00000 : 30.0000 ] 
set ytics nomirror
set y2tics
set ytics offset 0,0
set ylabel offset 0,0
set ytics textcolor rgb "violet"
set ylabel textcolor rgb "violet"
plot sin(x) axes x1y1 lt rgb "violet", cos(x) axes x1y2
unset key 

set origin 0,0
set xlabel "Taktzeit" 
set ylabel "Obere Temperatur in K" 
set xrange [ 0.00000 : 30.0000 ] 
set ytics nomirror
set ytics offset -10,0
set ylabel offset -10,0
set ytics textcolor rgb "red"
set ylabel textcolor rgb "red"
plot tan(x)
unset key 


unset key
unset multiplot
```

Thank you!

Comment: Not out-of-the-box. You must make a lot of manual settings to get this working: Fix all margins, use a different offset for the ytics of each plot, `set ytics offset -10,0`, `set ytics offset -20,0`... The most difficult thing is probably to automatically have equal number of ytics for all three plots.

Comment: Christoph, can you provide an example or at least explain how to get this done? As I wrote in the question, I am able to generate a single diagram with three axis, but I can´t generate three of them.

Comment: Could you then provide the data and the script you are currently using?

Comment: http://www40.zippyshare.com/v/wsHM7SzQ/file.html

http://www40.zippyshare.com/v/5i3LXhYX/file.html

These are the data and the plt-file. Let me know if you need anything else. Thank you.

Comment: Christoph, did you find any time to solve the problem? I wasn´t able to solve it... Thank you.

Comment: No, I didn't have a closer look. Basically you must combine the solution from the link you posted (one plot with three axes) with the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19133002/2604213, i.e. manually setting the `tmargin` and `bmargin` for each plot. Please make a real attempt to solve it yourself, which you haven't done judging from the plot file you posted...