# Gnuplot plotting with 3 y-axis

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I already read and checked other answers such as
[How to plot multiple y-axes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27390317/how-to-plot-multiple-y-axes)
this one. This example plotted all 3 y-axes on the left using "set multiplot".

But this is not what I want. What I want is a single plot with 3 y-axes. A plot with one y-axis on the left and 2 y-axes on the right. Or one on the right and 2 on the left. Something like
https://av8rdas.wordpress.com/2019/04/19/creating-a-third-axis-in-excel/
pictures in this link.

So far, for the plot with the second y-axis, I used axes x1y1 and axes x1y2 option with "set y2tics". But it seems that there are no "set y3tics" for the third y-axis.

Excel can do this so I'm sure Gnuplot can do this. But I just don't know how to. And I couldn't find how to...